# R - Turn List Into DataFrame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply

There is a list like this, starting from 1.

```
[[7158]]
[1] 81 72

[[7159]]
[1] 81 69

[[7160]]
[1] 81 79

[[7161]]
[1] 81 84
```

This needs to be changed to a data frame where the first number in each element is aligned in one data frame column, and the second number in each element is placed in the second column of a data frame.  So it should end up like this

```
> data.frame("col1" = c(81, 81, 81, 81), "col2" = c(72, 69, 79, 84))
  col1 col2
1   81   72
2   81   69
3   81   79
4   81   84
```

I tried doing `do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)` but it seems to place the numbers in a huge number of columns, not coerce it down to the two columns needed.  It would be pretty straight forward to do this with a loop but what is the R way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I think you might just be mislead by the column names. Try `do.call(rbind, my_list)` and then call `data.frame` on that instead. (That should be faster  than `rbind.data.frame` anyway).

Comment: You can also try `library(stringi); stri_list2matrix(my_list, byrow = TRUE)` or `t(simplify2array(my_list))`. You'll also need to wrap those in `as.data.frame` to get a `data.frame` as the output.

Comment: Yeah, that is the best way to do so, maybe you should add it as an answer for future reference.

Comment: ananda thanks.  if you put it as answer i'll mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 8):

Just set the names:

```
mylist <- list(c(81,72), c(81,63), c(81,79))
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, mylist), c("col1", "col2"))
#  col1 col2
#1   81   72
#2   81   63
#3   81   79
```

In contrast to some of the other solutions, this would also work for mixed data types:

```
mylist <- list(list("a", 72), list("b", 63), list("c", 79))
res <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, mylist), c("col1", "col2"))
str(res)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ col1: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
# $ col2: num  72 63 79
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but don't you think that running `type.convert` on the output after converting it to a `data.frame` would be faster than `rbind.data.frame` if mixed data types is a concern?

Answer (score 4):

You can try any of the following:

```
do.call(rbind, my_list)

t(simplify2array(my_list))

library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(my_list, byrow = TRUE)
```

All of the above would produce a two column `matrix` with the data that you describe, so you can then use `as.data.frame` to get a `data.frame`.

Timings for the above alternatives and @Roland's suggestion [can be found at this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/d4b30946b82cd3515ed1). To summarize, the "stringi" approach would be the fastest of the options presented so far. If I'm not mistaken, `rbindlist` in "data.table" should also support converting list of vectors--but I have not tested with the development version on GitHub to verify, so I haven't included that option here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
Reduce( rbind, lapply(t1, t) )
```

Comment: No, this is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

```
mylist = list(c(81, 72), c(81, 69), c(81, 79), c(81, 84))

f4 = function(x) 
{
    tlist = lapply(seq_along(x[[1]]), 
                   function(i) unlist(lapply(x, "[[", i)))
    structure(tlist, class = "data.frame", 
              row.names = .set_row_names(as.integer(length(tlist[[1]]))), 
              names = paste("col", seq_along(tlist), sep = ""))
}

f4(mylist)
#  col1 col2
#1   81   72
#2   81   69
#3   81   79
#4   81   84
```

And a benchmark with the other options:

```
library(stringi)              
f1 = function(x)
  setNames(as.data.frame(type.convert(stri_list2matrix(x, byrow = TRUE))), 
           paste("col", seq_along(x[[1]]), sep = ""))

f2 = function(x)
  setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, x), 
           paste("col", seq_along(x[[1]]), sep = ""))

f3 = function(x)
  setNames(as.data.frame(Reduce(rbind, lapply(x, t))), 
           paste("col", seq_along(x[[1]]), sep = "")) 

myls = replicate(1e3, sample(1e2), simplify = F)
identical(f1(myls), f2(myls))
#[1] TRUE
identical(f1(myls), f3(myls))
#[1] TRUE
identical(f1(myls), f4(myls))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(myls), f2(myls), f3(myls), f4(myls), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# f1(myls)  57.66834  58.46979  59.39131  61.43861 102.27333    10
# f2(myls) 393.81459 404.29019 418.03128 422.87740 494.79857    10
# f3(myls) 288.39078 299.51680 305.21727 314.75482 374.48683    10
# f4(myls)  52.54991  53.26575  55.34472  59.25559  75.19658    10
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [current development version of data.table, v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), there's a new function `transpose()`, which transposes a list. We can use that along with `setDT()` as follows.

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
ll = lapply(1:1e6, function(x) sample(100, 2))
dt = setDT(transpose(ll))

system.time(setDT(transpose(ll))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.073   0.000   0.073
```

If you want a data.frame, then you can use `setDF()` on this result (which converts a data.table to data.frame without any copies).